# Neo4j query to ignore parent nodes which doesn't satisfy a condition but keep the same structure

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree-like structure and I'm trying to get a Cypher query which will replace the parent node with the child if the parent node does not have a certain relation

for example the query: `MATCH (c)-[:CHILD_OF*]->(p {id:"123"}) return c` returns a structure like so (we don't care about what the other nodes are, the structure is the only thing that needs to be preserved)

```
()<-(A)

()<-()<-(B)<-()<-(C)

()<-(D)<-(E)<-()<-(F)
  \-(G)<-()<-H)
```

How could I get the query to ignore all nodes without a certain property but keep it the same structure like so:

```
(A)

(B)<-(C)

(D)<-(E)<-(F)

(G)<-(H)
```

Comment: If those parent nodes have other properties, do you want to drop those properties or copy them to the nearest remaining descendant node(s)?

Comment: all the () nodes will be ignored. It's only the structure that is needed

Comment: Do you actually want to delete nodes and create new relationships to the next valid child node, or do you only want to return a view of the structure omitting the unnecessary nodes, and showing relationships among the valid nodes even if those relationships aren't actually in the graph?

Comment: I only want to return a view of the node structure to do further querying on (even though those relationships don't exist in the actual graph). Nothing needs to be deleted.

Comment: Let me see if I have this right, You want to query several paths, and return specific nodes from each path?

Comment: Not necessarily. The query will return paths that leads to a common ancestor, but I would like the node connections to structured in a way so that there will be artificial relationships between nodes that meet a certain condition

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the procedures for creating [virtual nodes and relationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual) in APOC Procedures.

These will allow you to create virtual relationships, that will not be saved to the graph, but will be present and viewable in your query.

The tricky part will be creating those new virtual relationships. You'll likely be filtering down nodes in all paths to the nodes you're interested in. At that point you may need to use `apoc.coll.pairsMin()` in order to get each adjacent pair of nodes in the collection on a row so you can create the virtual relationships between them.

After all the virtual relationships are created (in the same cypher query), match from the root node using those virtual relationships, and you should see the graph you want.